# onPostExecute never called in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

this is my class with extends AsyncTask, my OnPostExecute is never called when i try to run this class,i don't know why,Kindly advice, Thousand of Thanks.

```
public  class loadingdata extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        Context mContext;
    public loadingdata(Context context) {
        super();
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        ToWebservice toWebservice = new ToWebservice(ScanPage.this);
        toWebservice.postDataHdr(Branch, DocNo, Status, Date);
        toWebservice.postDataDtl(DocNo);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (result != null) {
            waitDialog.cancel();

        } else {
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        waitDialog = ProgressDialog.show(mContext, "Working", "Please Wait", true, true);
        waitDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

    }

}
```

Comment: why doInBackground return null ?

Comment: You are returning null boss.

Comment: Your `result` is `null` so in else part just print something in `Log`. Your `onPostExecute` method is executed.

Comment: you have to return string to get called to post method and you are returning null from do in background method

Comment: Oh my mistake, Thanks guy!

Comment: @AnthonyTang read https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: @AnthonyTang Return result from doInBackground as currently it is return null and in onPostExecute method you have put the check for null.

Answer (score 2):

### Why returning null ?

> return null; // Problem here

**[doInBackground](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground(Params...))**

> This method contains the code which needs to be executed in
>   background. To notify that the background processing has been
>   completed we just need to use the return statements

```
 @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        ToWebservice toWebservice = new ToWebservice(ScanPage.this);
        toWebservice.postDataHdr(Branch, DocNo, Status, Date);
        toWebservice.postDataDtl(DocNo);
        return Status; // response
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Return any string like this,

```
 @Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    ToWebservice toWebservice = new ToWebservice(ScanPage.this);
    toWebservice.postDataHdr(Branch, DocNo, Status, Date);
    toWebservice.postDataDtl(DocNo);
    return Status;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You return Null In doinBackground
and in onPostExecute You Made condition
if (result != null)
So it`s Never called 
...
Just Remove the Condition In onPostExecute

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you return from `doInbackground()` is input for `postExecute()`.
 In your case you are returning null from `doInBackground()` and in `postExecute()`
Closing the dialog when result is not null.

just remove if condition from postExecute. because Dialog must be close in any case.

```
waitDialog.cancel();
```